"PluginNotFoundException: Unable to determine class for field type 'comment' found in 'field.storage.node.field_comments' "
We were on Drupal 7, and upgraded to Drupal 10 multi-site environment is hosted on Acquia. Since recent launch, Acquia PHP log is displaying this error.

PluginNotFoundException: Unable to determine class for field type 'comment' found in the 'field.storage.node.field_comments'

In documentation, I am finding it sounds like there might be a model missing. Looking for some troubleshooting advice on figuring out this error issue.
Below is the complete error.

[11-Jul-2024 13:50:07 UTC] Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: Unable to determine class for field type 'comment' found in the 'field.storage.node.field_comments' configuration in /var/www/html/docroot/core/modules/field/src/FieldStorageConfigStorage.php on line 167
#0 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Entity/ConfigEntityStorage.php(186): Drupal\field\FieldStorageConfigStorage->mapFromStorageRecords()
#1 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php(312): Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityStorage->doLoadMultiple()
#2 /var/www/html/docroot/core/modules/views/views.views.inc(191): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->loadMultiple()
#3 /var/www/html/docroot/core/modules/views/src/ViewsData.php(228): views_views_data()
#4 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleHandler.php(388): Drupal\views\ViewsData->Drupal\views{closure}()
#5 /var/www/html/docroot/core/modules/views/src/ViewsData.php(227): Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAllWith()
#6 /var/www/html/docroot/core/modules/views/src/ViewsData.php(151): Drupal\views\ViewsData->getData()
#7 /var/www/html/docroot/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/Derivative/ViewsEntityRow.php(94): Drupal\views\ViewsData->get()
#8 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator.php(101): Drupal\views\Plugin\Derivative\ViewsEntityRow->getDerivativeDefinitions()
#9 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator.php(87): Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDerivatives()
#10 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Plugin/DefaultPluginManager.php(323): Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDefinitions()
#11 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Plugin/DefaultPluginManager.php(205): Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->findDefinitions()
#12 /var/www/html/docroot/core/modules/views/views.module(146): Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions()
#13 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/Registry.php(479): views_theme()
#14 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/Registry.php(372): Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->processExtension()
#15 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleHandler.php(388): Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->Drupal\Core\Theme{closure}()
#16 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/Registry.php(371): Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAllWith()
#17 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/Registry.php(255): Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->build()
#18 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Utility/ThemeRegistry.php(88): Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->get()
#19 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Utility/ThemeRegistry.php(69): Drupal\Core\Utility\ThemeRegistry->initializeRegistry()
#20 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/Registry.php(291): Drupal\Core\Utility\ThemeRegistry->__construct()
#21 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/ThemeManager.php(141): Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->getRuntime()
#22 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(480): Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render()
#23 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(240): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender()
#24 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(153): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render()
#25 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(627): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->Drupal\Core\Render{closure}()
#26 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(152): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext()
#27 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/BareHtmlPageRenderer.php(66): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->renderRoot()
#28 /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Render/BareHtmlPageRenderer.php(76): Drupal\Core\Render\BareHtmlPageRenderer->renderBarePage()
#29 /var/www/html/docroot/core/includes/install.core.inc(1074): Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Render\BareHtmlPageRenderer->renderBarePage()
#30 /var/www/html/docroot/core/includes/install.core.inc(163): install_display_output()
#31 /var/www/html/docroot/core/install.php(48): install_drupal()
#32 {main} request_id="v-7ac6bc72-3f8c-11ef-911a-33f7b0362b7c"


I'm not sure the modern versions of Drupal (8+) have ever had a comment field type, I think they were always entity references. In theory that config/content should've been upgraded as part of a migration. It's technically possible to change field types and update content tables in-situ (i.e. what you'd need to do here), but from experience I can say it's quite difficult and needs a good understanding of how the entity/field system works. Your best bet might be to create new comment fields, and then create a custom migration to get just the comment data across from the old site

Clive - thanks for your input. :)
